# xCode crashes when I drag custom object into UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, interface-builder

I have a custom button that is a subclassed `UIButton`. When I try to drag it into a `UIScrollView` in IB Xcode immediately crashes. What gives?

I have this custom button working inside a `UIScrollView` in at least one other location in my app. Any ideas?

[image: Xcode crash]
[image]

---

**UPDATE:**
Uncheck "Use Autolayout" in the File Inspector fixes this problem. See answer below.

Comment: Which version of Xcode you are working on?

Comment: 4.5... good thinking. could be a problem with the dev preview I suppose.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same that is why I asked Xcode version first. I also faced this issue some time before on developer preview.

Comment: *sigh* If you're using Xcode 4.5 then this isn't the place to post these questions.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't suspect that was a problem until @BornCoder suggested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION: Uncheck "Use Autolayout" in the File Inspector**

Thanks to @BornCoder I decided to try running this on my laptop running Xcode 4.4. When I tried to build I got an error saying this version of Xcode doesn't support Autolayout. I didn't intend to use Autolayout, it looks like Xcode 4.5 does automatically. Unchecking the box fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

> I have this custom button working inside a UIScrollView in at least
>   one other location in my app. Any ideas?

I  could crash several Java editor like this. The problem it was in my custom component code:
I have added code, which the designer ( Interface builder) have executed to show my component.

Take extra care at `init`, `viewDidLoad` methods in your Button code.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know exactly, But once the same kind of issue happened with me.
My problem was that some of my drawing methods were being called recursively, causing the Xcode to crash. I handled those recursive calls and issue got fixed.